# Custom LinkedList: remove method does not work as expected

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

I'm implementing the `remove()` method of a custom `LinkedList` class, but it does not remove any items from the list, and I can't figure out why.

Here's how I do it:

```
public void remove(int position) {
        if (position < 0 || position >= size) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(
                    "position should be beween 0 and size - 1");
        }

        Cell current = top;
        for (int i = 0; i < position; i++) {
            current = current.next;
        }
        current = current.next.next;
        size--;
}
```

This method tries to remove an item between 2 nodes (removing first node and last node cases are ignored).

This is the test case I am executing, and after trying to remove the element with index 2, it still prints the hole list:

```
CustomList<String> list = new CustomList<String>();
list.add("Hello");
list.add("morena");
list.add("What");
list.add("Miranda");
list.add("Aston");      

list.remove(2);

list.printAll();
```

For completion, here's the full implementation of the list:

```
public class CustomList<T> {

    private class Cell {
        T data;
        Cell next;

        public Cell(T data) {
            this.data = data;
        }
    }

    private Cell top;
    private int size;

    public void add(T data) {
        addAtEndInOn(data);
        size++; 
    }

    /**
     * adds an item at the end of the list in O(n) by iterating the whole list
     * before adding the node
     */
    private void addAtEndInOn(T data) {
        if (top == null) {
            top = new Cell(data);
        } else {
            Cell current = top;
            while (current.next != null) {
                current = current.next;
            }
            current.next = new Cell(data);
        }
    }

    public void remove(int position) {
        if (position < 0 || position >= size) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "position should be a positive number");
        }

        Cell current = top;
        for (int i = 0; i < position; i++) {
            current = current.next;
        }
        current = current.next.next;
        size--;
    }

    public void printAll() {
        Cell current = top;
        while (current != null) {
            System.out.println(current.data);
            current = current.next;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`current = current.next.next` changes nothing in your list.

In order to remove an element, you need to write :

```
current.next = current.next.next;
```

This would remove the element that is next to the current element. It that's not the element you meant to remove, you should change the for loop so that it stops when current is the element before the one you want to remove.

Make sure to test that `current.next` is not null, to avoid `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 2):

[image: You have to break the link, not just change the position of current]

You have to break the link, not just change the position of current. The link is represented by current.next